# What should we have to do to go back on track?

Tags: discussion

As comparing our progress from last year our questions per day is decreased which should be  15 questions per day for a healthy beta but we fall from 5.3 questions per day to 4.5 questions per day. We have reached 2k+ question but our increase rate is quite low. So what should we are going to do about it?

Comment: umm... things??

Comment: Last sentence didn't come out right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be honest, I think we're kinda leveling out.  Unless there's a major movie that raises a lot of questions fairly often, the number of questions is going to be relatively low.  But that's ok, as other sites like [rpg.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) have shown.  The major factor is that we keep a relatively consistent crowd, keep good quality questions, and provide the best quality answers.

Comment: +1 agreed after seeing the rpg stats.